# Not able to browser created website in IIS

Tags: iis, web

I have configured sites in IIS in Windows server 2012 (IIS version 6.2) but after successful configuration I am not able to browse the site, getting the error 'This page cannot be displayed' while browsing locally. And while using the URL with port number and browsing from remote getting http 500 error.

Have tried so many settings and changes like permission,directory browsing (enabling), setting up of the default page (start page), but with no luck. Same error, this error is common across all the 7 sites. All sites are of .net 4 version with properly configured app pools.

All required windows features have been installed.

Can any one advice in this regard?

Comment: Have you ensured that the site folders are usable by the IIS_USER in the security tab?

Comment: yes permission for machine name / IIS_User has been given.

Comment: Using the IIS browse feature can you tell me what other errors you are getting? do you have debug enabled in web.config?

Comment: I am getting the two errors this page cannot be displayed and http 500 while trying to browser locally from IIS (inside the server) and remotely.

Comment: I know this is basic, but have you bounced the server and checked if maybe one of the servers services was stopped?

Comment: the reqd services www, IIS are all up and running.

Comment: Are the handler mappings set up correctly for ISAPI.dll?Make sure that the script mapping points to the ISAPI .dll file that can process the request. To do this, follow these steps:

    Click Start, click Run, type inetmgr.exe, and then click OK.
    In IIS Manager, expand server name, expand Web sites, and then click the Web site that you want to modify.
    In Features view, double-click Handler Mappings.
    Make sure that the script mapping points to the correct ISAPI .dll file.


For example, .asp files should map to the %windir%\system32\inetsrv\asp.dll file.

Comment: the .aspx and .asp extensions are set up properly, no changes

Comment: That is all I got for that little, if I were there maybe I could think of something, but its hard when its not right in front of you.  best of luck and don't give up!

Comment: @Raj check the windows eventviewer for any errors. Also, is your webapp using urlrewriting? If yes check UrlRewrite IIS extension is installed on the server.

Comment: https://www.jexusmanager.com/en/latest/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html Since you showed almost no information regarding your site bindings, you might run Binding Diagnostics and paste what it says as part of your question for others to review.

Comment: with regards to the binding I am using only local binding server name : port number. The port number alone varies for the different sites.

Comment: The host file entry is also made but still, I am getting no break through. default website alone is working.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `IIS Apppool\{App pool name}` has access to the folder the website is running from.

Make sure the you have the proper features installed by going through

`Add Roles and Features -> Server Roles -> Web Server (IIS) -> Web Server -> Application Development -> ASP.Net 4.5`

Comment: Second one I have enabled and installed, first will check the app pool is default with 4 version.

Comment: tried setting changes and security of the app pool to network account / system account. But it does not work.

Comment: Got the sites working by adding privilege like enabling anonymous and windows authentication , adding machine-name/IIS_IUSR to the virtual directory / website permission.